# Linked List Fields Adding

Tags: c

I am attempting to make my `findUpdate` method which updates my linkedlist with `accountNumber = account` and `balance = amount`. If the **accountnumber** does not exist, then a new node is created.

However, I am not sure how to add nodes to a linked list. Also, should I initialize ahead variable null here like this?

## include

```
struct ACCOUNT {

    int accountNumber;
    float balance;
    struct ACCOUNT *next;
};


struct ACCOUNT *head = NULL;
void findUpdate(int account, float amount) {
    struct ACCOUNT* temp = (struct ACCOUNT*) malloc(sizeof(struct ACCOUNT));
    temp->accountNumber = account;
    temp->balance = amount;
}
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'll post as an answer instead.

You should initialize with NULL.
To add, it depends where you want to add the new node. At the beginning, mid or end of the list?

There a very good tutorial [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/) that explains each one of this cases.

Comment: I read this, but I am not taking a pointer as input. I would like to add every new node at the end of the list

Comment: Ok, usually we send the Head of the list to our function as a pointer. Another option is to declare it globally (I think you did it, but the code isn't complete).
The link provided cover how to add it at the end, it should be fine to understand by reading it.